Is anko commons no longer available for use in Android projects?
We are seeing the following error in a Bitrise build of an Android project.

Could not GET 'http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven/org/jetbrains/anko/anko-commons/0.10.8/anko-commons-0.10.8.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I know anko commons was deprecated some time ago but this has been working up until now. Just trying to determine if this is a permanent thing, or it has something to do with the Crowdstrike snafu.  Seems like if it weren't available permanently it would report something other than a 403.
Clearly this dependency needs to be removed, but that will take a while and we're trying to do a release. Even a short-term solution would be helpful because it would allow us to get the release out and then address this immediately after.

I don't know why that is coming up with tokbox.bintray.com. However, I think this is the official JetBrains repo location, and it too returns 403. In principle, you can get versions elsewhere, but they're behind a login wall. If you have a machine that still builds, you'll have the POM and AAR in the Gradle cache and could host it locally for the short term.

tokbox.bintray.com is specified in a maven block, I don't know why. That is how it was when I inherited it. It does build locally, so I'm considering that as a short-term way around it.  Thanks!

Have you found a solution?? I've got the same problem: missing anko dependency in a legacy project that need updating.

Hi @akamuza, as far as I can tell, anko is no longer available.  In my case, the legacy app was using a small number of convenience functions from anko, and so I created equivalent functions in the project and replaced the anko functions with those.  I think anko is mostly convenience functions so I doubt there will is a replacement for it.

As far as I can tell, anko is no longer available. The app was using a small number of convenience functions from anko, and so I created equivalent functions in the project and replaced the anko functions with those. I think anko is mostly convenience functions so I doubt there will is a replacement for it.
